# Django GET and POST handling methods

Tags: python, django

I want a way to automatically route GET and POST requests to subsequent methods in a centralized way.
I want to create my handler in the following way.

```
class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        #handle get requests

    def post(self):
        #handle post requests
```

This is what webapp2 does and I very much like the style, is it possible to do in Django?
I also want the view in Class-method style. What kind of BaseHandler and router should I write.

HINT: Use django generic views.

Comment: I assume your second def get(self): was supposed to be def post(self): ?

Comment: To be fair, you described what you want but you haven't described what you've tried. You seem to expect us to write everything for you...

Comment: Please don't downvote this comment :D http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1912/ This is definitely not the way to develop something (good) in Django. Please read the other comments in that page!

Comment: I was hoping that this was an often used pattern so there would be some kind of ready to use BaseHandler.

Comment: @specialscope Django has a different way to do it. Not harder, but different. :) Just learn it!

Comment: Yes I am fine with that but I just dont want to repeat if reqest.type is POST because majority of my requests are POST. Is there some elegant way to handle it?

Comment: Thanks all it seems like to achieve what I want to do I need to use django generic views. Cool!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is supported in Django as [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views). You can extend the generic class `View` and add methods like `get()`, `post()`, `put()` etc. E.g. -

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is GET request')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is POST request')
```

The `dispatch()` method from `View` class handles this-

> ### **dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)**
>
> The view part of the view – the
>   method that accepts a request argument plus arguments, and returns a
>   HTTP response.
>
> **The default implementation will inspect the HTTP method and attempt to
>   delegate to a method that matches the HTTP method; a GET will be
>   delegated to get(), a POST to post(), and so on.**
>
> By default, a HEAD request will be delegated to get(). If you need to
>   handle HEAD requests in a different way than GET, you can override the
>   head() method. See Supporting other HTTP methods for an example.
>
> The default implementation also sets request, args and kwargs as
>   instance variables, so any method on the view can know the full
>   details of the request that was made to invoke the view.

Then you can use it in `urls.py` -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from myapp.views import MyView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^mine/$', MyView.as_view(), name='my-view'),
)
```