# how to merge django urls for GET and POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need help, I got a path() issue when I was trying route GET/POST request on a single url:
When I want to add a server recored, I would do a POST {"serverid":1,"hostname":"test server"} on the url:

/api/server/

but sometime I'd like to query the server by serverid, then I had to write another path() mapping for GET:

/api/server/<int:serverid>/

Obviously they both can be in one view class/method, I believe this is more duplicated, but how can I merge these two url into one path? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see the link below :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668441/django-get-and-post-handling-methods

Answer (score 0):

you have to put only id=None so that will be accessible by both urls
and also put url patterns like this

urls.py

```
path('test/', views.test, name='test'),
path('test/<int:id>', views.test, name='test'),
```

views.py

```
def test(request, id=None):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
```

for view

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request,id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Get view!')
    def post(self,request,id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Post view!')
```

you can also make two views in one like this

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request,id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if id:
            return HttpResponse('Get view with id')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Get view without id')
    def post(self,request,id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if id:
            return HttpResponse('Post view with id!')
```

Comment: Thanks Kishan, I am new to django, would you please show me a CBV example too? Really appreciate.